# Proxying a Flask app with gunicorn and nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, gunicorn, flask

I have a Flask application that is currently being served on a machine (call it `first_vm`) using the following command in `supervisord`:

```
gunicorn run:app -b 0.0.0.0:8002 -k socketio.sgunicorn.GeventSocketIOWorker --workers 1
```

This application is also reverse proxied *locally* on port `80` by `nginx`, such that `http://first_vm/` will serve the application as expected.

What I would like to do is to reverse proxy the application on a different server (say `second_vm`), such that `http://second_vm/my_app` serves the application by hitting `gunicorn` on `first_vm:8002`.

This is the nginx configuration I currently have on `second_vm`:

```
location /my_app {
    proxy_pass http://first_vm:8002/;

    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}
```

This configuration works fine in that it serves my application on `http://second_vm/my_app`, but static files (e.g. JS/CSS) don't get served properly because the browser tries to fetch them from `http://second_vm/` instead of `http://second_vm/my_app`.

For example, Chrome will tell me that it `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status 404` in the following scenario:

```
http://second_vm/blueprint/static/css/bootstrap.min.css   <-- what Chrome fails to fetch
http://second_vm/my_app/blueprint/static/css/bootstrap.min.css   <-- what it should fetch
```

Could anyone help me make this work?

Answer (score 3):

After many trials and tribulations I discovered a blog post that solved the issue for me as well. http://albertoconnor.ca/blog/2011/Sep/15/hosting-django-under-different-locations It mentions Django, but otherwise it's the same software (namely gunicorn and nginx) and the fix is the same as the root cause is the same.

Edit:

Essentially the flask app is missing the SCRIPT_NAME header which tells it where the app lives so adding 
`proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /my_app;` is the first start, but then you need to fix the redirect as well, as there is some under the hood fixing of urls as well, so `proxy_redirect http://first_vm:8002/my_app http://$host/my_app;` should prevent it from doing things like returning relative addresses between the first_vm and the second_vm.